# Google sheets incorrect formula for conditional forrmating

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm getting the incorrect formula for this condition.

```
=AND(ISBLANK($C6), NOT(ISBLANK($I6)))
```

What I want to achieve - I want to check if the current cell, for example, C6 is not empty and if the corresponding I cell (with the same number) has value - if both are true apply formatting.

Comment: use semicolon instead of comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to check whether C6 and I6 are not empty:

`=AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C6));NOT(ISBLANK($I6)))`

You haven't provided much information in your post. An example of the data and explaining why your original formula isn't working would help.

*Edit for new information provided in comment*

OP's Google Sheets locale is set to Polish which uses a semicolon (;) for separating arguments. This is the same for most of Europe. In other countries, a comma (,) is used instead. Here is an explanation of these differences: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/sheets-location/

Putting the above formula as conditional formatting works when setting the file's locale to Polish. Only cells C6:C8 and C13:C14 are highlighted as they are the only ones with values in both columns.

[image: Screenshot of Google Sheets with the above formula]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response. As I said in my question I try to make double check - data is not important here - I'm just trying to check whenever the cell in row C has not any value (text/number - it does not matter) and the corresponding Cell in row I have any data. Google Sheets won't let me apply this condition it says it's an incorrect formula - my range is C6:C19. After putting the formula in formula input in custom formatting it gets a red border and says "incorrect formula "

Comment: I have updated the post showing it working - what are you doing differently?

Comment: I have no idea, it just won't let me apply the formula - https://pasteboard.co/a0323srdk3hy.jpg - a formula: =AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C6)),NOT(ISBLANK($I6)))

Comment: Is your Google Sheets locale set to Polish? For formulas in most of Europe, you separate arguments using a semicolon. I've updated the answer with this information and the formula should actually be =AND(NOT(ISBLANK($C6));NOT(ISBLANK($I6)))

Answer (score 0):

You could use two conditional formatting rules.  Sometimes it is less of a headache than trying to figure out the correct formula.  Also, depending on the complexity of the formula, it can also be faster to evaluate.

Screenshots below:
[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Screenshot2]